# How to fix 'Incorrect result size: expected 1, actual 0' when I fetch a row by ID?

Tags: java, sql, spring, jdbctemplate

**Context:**

I have quite a few tables in my database. I don't have explicit entity classes in java but instead I store info about columns and values in a special class which looks like this:

```
public class Spravochnik extends BaseEntity {  
    private List<String> columnName;
    private List<List<String>> valuesInRows;
    public List<String> getColumnName() {
        return columnName;
    }
    public void setColumnName(List<String> columnName) {
        this.columnName = columnName;
    }
    public List<List<String>> getValuesInRows() {
        return valuesInRows;
    }
    public void setValuesInRows(List<List<String>> valuesInRows) {
        this.valuesInRows = valuesInRows;
    }   
}
```

Base Entity just has an id as all my tables have one, and here are all the other fields (column names) and all the inserted values by rows (values in rows is a list of values in one row wrapped in another list to get list of rows which in turn are each a list of values in them).
I also have a rowmapper:

```
public class SpravochnikRowMapper implements RowMapper<Spravochnik> {
    @Override
    public Spravochnik mapRow(ResultSet rs, int arg1) throws SQLException {
        Spravochnik spr = new Spravochnik();
        ResultSetMetaData rsmeta = rs.getMetaData();
        List<String> columnNames = new ArrayList<>();
        List<List<String>> valuesInRows = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
        int columnCount = rsmeta.getColumnCount();

        for(int column = 1; column <= columnCount; column++){
            columnNames.add(rsmeta.getColumnName(column));
        }
        spr.setColumnName(columnNames);
        
        do {
            List<String> values = new ArrayList<>();
            for(int column = 1; column <= columnCount; column++){
                values.add(rs.getString(column));
            }
            
            valuesInRows.add(values);
        }while(rs.next());
        spr.setValuesInRows(valuesInRows);

        return spr;
    }
}
```

So, I have a method to get one row based on its id (yes, at first i'm getting one form of id from another but it is not so important):

```
    @Override
    public Spravochnik selectOne(String id) {
        return spravochnikDao.selectOne(getSpravId(id), getRowId(id) );
    }
    
    protected int getSpravId(String id) {
        return Integer.valueOf(id.substring(0, 3));
    }
    
    protected int getRowId(String id) {
        return Integer.valueOf(id);
    }
```

**Actual problematic method**
so in dao implement:

```
    @Override
    public Spravochnik selectOne(int spravochnikId, int rowId) {
        return jdbctemplate.queryForObject(getQueryDinamicTable(SQL_SELECT_ROW, getSpravNameAtId(spravochnikId)),
                new SpravochnikRowMapper(), rowId);
    }
```

The thing is, it works perfectly fine with tables containing 2 columns (id and another one; all my tables but one satisfy this) but when I try to get a row from my only table which has 3 columns, it says

> org.springframework.dao.EmptyResultDataAccessException: Incorrect result size: expected 1, actual 0". Again, it works fine when I get a row from a table with 2 columns and not when with 3. Guess the problem is either in rowmapper or in method itself. If you need extra information, feel free to ask and thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The `mapRow` method would be called for each row available. Hence, doing a `rs.next()` is not a good practice. You may rewrite the mapper like below:

```
public class SpravochnikRowMapper implements RowMapper<Spravochnik> {

    private List<String> columnNames;
    private int columnCount;

    @Override
    public Spravochnik mapRow(ResultSet rs, int arg1) throws SQLException {
        Spravochnik spr = new Spravochnik();
        if (columnNames == null) {
            ResultSetMetaData rsmeta = rs.getMetaData();
            columnNames = new ArrayList<>();
            columnCount = rsmeta.getColumnCount();
            for(int column = 1; column <= columnCount; column++){
                columnNames.add(rsmeta.getColumnName(column));
            }

        }

        List<List<String>> valuesInRows = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
        spr.setColumnName(columnNames);

        List<String> values = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int column = 1; column <= columnCount; column++){
            values.add(rs.getString(column));
        }

        valuesInRows.add(values);
        spr.setValuesInRows(valuesInRows);
        return spr;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! It still behaves the same on my 3-column table though...

Comment: Please share the return value of - getQueryDinamicTable

Comment: protected String getQueryDinamicTable(String query, String tableName) {
  return query.replace(SQL_RPL_TABLE_NAME, tableName).intern();
 }

Comment: Thank you, I have resolved the issue, it turned out that the warning was coming not because of a faulty rowmapper but because of a typo in sql table and data setup structure for this particular table